# Base64 string to UIImage Issue

Tags: swift, uiimage, base64, decode, decoding

#### Disclaimer: There's many questions on SO asking the same thing here. I've attempted to directly follow the solutions on those questions with no success. I've tried to avoid posting this duplicate.

Hello,

I'm having trouble decoding a base64 encoded string to an image in Swift. I've tried with a few different sets of data but they all don't seem to decode properly, as the results are always `nil`.

After quite a bit of reasearch, I've concluded that the string needs to be decoded into `Data`, create an image from that data and set a `UIImageView`'s image to it. Simple enough, right?

```
let base64String: String = ...
let decodedData: Data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: [])
let decodedImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: decodedData)
myImageView.image = decodedImage
```

However, after all my various attempts, the data ends up being `nil`, and I'm unable to create the image.

I have a feeling it might be the data that I'm using, but online conversion tools seem to have no problem using it. See below for a sample of my data and a website that I use for conversion.

[String example](https://pastebin.com/rE83R8py) /
[Online converter](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) / 
[Actual image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yTS3NI74N-CYE4OeiDVZXqMln1Yij1ls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Base64 string

```
%2F9j%2F4AAQSk...Z2uHi4%2BTl5ufo6...jtTGf%2FZ
```

contains "[percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) hexadecimal sequences",
such as "%2F" for "/", or "%2B" for "+".

That is a variant used in [URL applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications), but `Data` does not handle it automatically. Therefore you have to remove the
percent encodings first:

```
if let percentDecoded = base64String.removingPercentEncoding,
    let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: percentDecoded) {
    // ...
}
```